# ZendPdf without Zend Framework

Tags: php, pdf, zend-framework

I am trying to use ZendPdf without the Zend Framework.  I have added the appropriate things to composer.json and can successfully load and write to an existing PDF.

My issue occurs when I try cloning the loaded PDF into a new PDF.  At the moment, I am just working in a Test class, so everything is currently just in the constructor.  My code is the following

```
public function __construct($fileData) {

    $newPdf = new PdfDocument();

    foreach($fileData as $name => $extension){
        if($extension == "application/pdf") {

            $pdf = PdfDocument::load($name);

            foreach ($pdf->pages as $page) {
                $clonedPage = clone $page;
                $newPdf->pages[] = $clonedPage;
            }

        } else {
            var_dump("NO");
        }
    }
    try {
        $newPdf->save( 'example.pdf' );
    } catch(RuntimeException $e) {
        var_dump("ERROR IS " . $e);
    }
}
```

I have done some debugging, and the existing PDF loads fine.  The error occurs when saving the new pdf.  The error is

```
string(1585) "ERROR IS exception 'ZendPdf\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Undefined property
: \ZendPdf\InternalType\ArrayObject::$value' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\zendframework\zendpdf
\library\ZendPdf\InternalType\ArrayObject.php:66
```

Is there any reason I am getting this, or is there any way to debug it further keeping in mind that I do not have the whole framework (only ZendPdf, Zend Stdlib, Zend Memory and Zend Hydrator).

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the source code. https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf/blob/master/library/ZendPdf/InternalType/ArrayObject.php#L66 From what I see, `$newPdf->pages[]` is missing. Why do you clone the page and insert it in an array instead of just inserting it?